# Error: Max retries exceeded with url appear when using web3.py

Tags: web3.py, web3-providers

Here is my code:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, IPCProvider

web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

print(web3.eth.blockNumber)
```

Below is the error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10d8951d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks all

Comment: Would you update your question to include the command you used to start your Ethereum node, and the output up through the first couple of logs showing that blocks are syncing?

Answer (score 2):

All we can tell from the information provided in the question is that there is no server responding at `http://localhost:8545`.

This could be a variety of problems. Some common problems are:

- The node was never started
- The node was started, but it's not on the same computer as Web3.py (ie~ not on `localhost`)
- The node is local, and started, but without the arguments needed to start the HTTP server
- The node is local, started, and serving HTTP, but serving on a port other than 8545

Answer (score 0):

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8545): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new
>   connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))

Seems to be ipc is running in different port/ip. Check with g/eth client.